# double sequence question: convergence of the average over one index, when the sequence converges over another index

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, double-sequence

Let $\{a_{N,i}:i\geq 1, N\geq 1\}$ be a real valued double sequence, such that,
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} a_{N,i} = a_i, \quad\text{for each $i\geq 1$,}
$$
where, $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$, for all $i\geq 1$. Can we conclude that,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N a_{N,i} - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right| \rightarrow 0,\quad\text{as $N\rightarrow\infty$.}
$$
Is there any counterexample to this statement?

Comment: $A_{N,i}=N$ if $i =N$ and $0$ otherwise. $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Does it help to prove the claim, if $a_{N,i}$ and $a_i$ are bounded (say within $[0,1]$)?

Comment: No. it doesn't. For example take $a_{N,i}=1$ if $N/2 \leq i \leq N$ and $0$ otherwise.